# Why did the value in raster layer changed after importing it in R

Tags: raster, arcmap, r

I opened the raster layer in ArcMap where the raster statistics showed the range of the raster value was -1 to 3.
[image]

However, when I imported it in R for further analysis, the raster value changed.

```
> ##### import all cloud cover raster files in a single folder as a list #####
> cloudlist <- list.files(path = ".", pattern='reliability.tif$', all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)
> cloudlist
[1] "MOSAIC_TMP_2000049.hdfout.250m_16_days_pixel_reliability.tif"

> allcloud<-stack(cloudlist)
> allcloud
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 4846, 13056, 63269376, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 250, 250  (x, y)
extent     : -1253475, 2010525, 2211480, 3422980  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=51 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : MOSAIC_TMP_2000049.hdfout.250m_16_days_pixel_reliability 
min values :                                                     -128 
max values :                                                      127 

> brickcloud<-brick(allcloud)
> brickcloud
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 4846, 13056, 63269376, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 250, 250  (x, y)
extent     : -1253475, 2010525, 2211480, 3422980  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=51 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : MOSAIC_TMP_2000049.hdfout.250m_16_days_pixel_reliability 
min values :                                                        0 
max values :                                                      255 
>
```

Could anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: Hard to say precisely without a copy of the data file to reproduce this, but summary statistics of large rasters are often approximated from sub-samples (or it would take too long to compute). This is possibly happening here. What is `range(values(brickcloud))` and `allcloud`? That should read all the pixel values and give a definitive answer not from summaries.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you very much for your answer. The range(values(brickcloud)) and range(values(allcloud)) is from 0 to 255. Actually, this is the layer of 250m 16 days pixel reliability summary quality assessment from the MOD13Q1(16-day 250m) VI product. The MODIS Vegetation Index User’s Guide documented that this layer's units are Rank, Data type is int8, the scale factor is NA and the valid range is from 0 to 3. I want to identify the cell in NDVI raster which is ranked as 2 or 3 (which indicate the cells are covered by cloud or snow) and then replace it as NA.